# mongodb php $push update with array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection structured like this:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "immagini" : {
    "imgid" : ObjectId("551969b426a8a4e00800002b"),
    "title" : "ceccotti",
    "contenttype" : "image/jpeg"
  }
}
```

I'd like to add an other document into the array "immagini" and I'm trying like this:

```
$filter = array('_id'=>1);
$update = array('$push'=>array('immagini'=>array (
  "imgid" => $id,
  "title" => $title,
  "contenttype"=> $imageType)));
$coll->update($filter,$update);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoWriteConcernException' with message 'localhost:27017: The field 'immagini' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: 1}' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tesi\upload_img_to_array.php:54 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tesi\upload_img_to_array.php(54): MongoCollection->update(Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tesi\upload_img_to_array.php on line 54
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `immagini` is an object so you cannot use [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: Oh I see. I meant `immagini` to be an array of documents. What should I do to implement a solution like this in php?